# Transaction per second - vuser relation

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I want to setup loadtest with Loadrunner. System requirements are as below

*1- max 30K users can be online  i want to test if system can reach 15TPS.

2- i want to test if system can reach 2000TPS while some of online 
users can visit 5 different pages. With how many vusers i should do this test ?*

For both browsing and login operations response time is 0.1 or 0.2 seconds but think-time is ignored for login operation but 5 minutes for browsing operations. ( This value can be changed for sake of simplecity.) For login operation i setup vusers count to 30 and used 1000 iterations for reaching 15TPS.

i know that we can calculate vusers with below

> number of required VUsers = required transaction per seconds * user
>   scenario length (sec)

but i m not sure how to apply this to second scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Required TPS =15
users   5
Pacing  =5/15

use this and it will work